# MySQL get everything up to the last day of the last month

Tags: php, mysql, database, date

I need to get records out of my database where the date stamp on them is before the last day of last month.

I am currently using this:

```
AND jobs.creationDate <= date_format(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-'+last_day(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
```

Which I'm not sure is working or not.

Is their a simpler way of achieving what I want and is what I have used correct (it's very hard to test this in my case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jobs.creationDate < LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the last day of the prior month with the following:

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH));
```

Comment: As Asad points out, feel free to replace NOW() with CURDATE().